# Estimate what percentage of math articles on Arxiv are eventually published.

Tags: soft-question

I was looking through arxiv and was curious about what percentage of the math articles on there get published. Does anyone know or care to take a guess?

Comment: In one sense of the word "published", 100% ! (with the occasional piece later withdrawn).  A bit less facetiously, some of the review papers, for instance, on ArXiv are not bound for journals, but are intended to be released for reading there.  ArXiv takes the place of the old "pre-print" system (mailing drafts of work to colleagues for discussion, "bragging rights", whatever), and some amount of it probably never sees preservation in a journal later.  With the _vast_ amount of publication activity in all forms these days, I doubt _anybody_ could give you a reliable percentage...